# Django migrations for docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-models, docker-compose

I have been trying to resolve an issue i am having currently, but i have not found any adequate solution neither here or elsewhere, so i was hoping someone here might have an answer. I have gotten to a point where i know what the problem is but not how to resolve it.

Basically i have a website running django/postgres/nginx, it runs smoothly and i can make new models and migrate them, but if i try to add a field to the model:

```
from django.db import models

class project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField()
    #Added in second round of migrations 
    #Description = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True, null=True)
```

What i would normally do is initially build and spin up my container

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
```

And within my entrypoint file i run makemigrations and migrate.

The first round it works well, but if i add the Description field to my model, spin down and rebuild the container to allow the new field to be included in my container, the new container is build without the initial migration, and isntead with a new migration. This results in any previous postgres tables not getting the new field added and a server error 500 when i try to request the data as previous tables now do not have the expected columns.

Therefore my question is how would you normally manage models for containerized django apps to ensure you maintain all migrations? Or is there another solution i am not aware of?

It might be a silly question but i am quite new to this and would appreciate any help you could offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makemigrations` should be done in development phase, and add the migrate files (000x prefix files) to source control.

Then, after several times' modify, you should have something like:

```
0001_first_round_change.py
0002_second_round_change_for_description.py
......
```

Every time when docker container start, migrate these files, a useful procedure for this operation could be seen in [Django Commands: makemigrations or migrate?](https://sixfeetup.com/blog/django-migrate-or-makemigrations)

And, [here](https://git.lavasoftware.org/lava/lava/-/tree/master/lava_scheduler_app/migrations) is an opensource project example which they use the same method to do migrate, FYI.

Comment: Aha, alright this actually makes a lot of sense to me. So just to make entirely sure, currently i am running my postgres locally as a service within my docker-compose file. Under different circumstances i guess i would just run the development outside of the container but still retain access to a RDS hosted by e.g. amazon. So i could still work with the database in dev?

Comment: I'm not sure I catch you. What I understand is: dev phase could be independent from ops phase. Just take care every database structure change be `makemigrations`. Then in production environment just do `migrate` for all migrate files, if db change, the command will simply skip it, like [this](https://git.lavasoftware.org/lava/lava/-/blob/master/docker/share/entrypoints/lava-server.sh#L219). So development in local ok to use local container, also ok to not use container in local just depends on your development habit. Have a experiment for yourself first maybe better...

Answer (score 1):

1. The `migrate` operation is dangerous and you should never do it automatically.
2. The recommended default behavior of entrypoint file is running your app server.
3. If you want to migrate your database, try `docker exec` for running command in container.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, i will remove the migration from the entrypoint file and keep the recommended behaviour in mind.

However i tried running with the ```exec``` command before, but that still wont solve the problem of the migrations being wiped on every rebuild of the model.

Currently i modify the models after spinning down, and as i spin up and build any ```makemigration``` call i make is not save to my local machine

Comment: @AlexS you should run `makemigration` on your local machine and add migration files to git. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#workflow